# Does a geometric morphism $f\colon \cal E\to F$ preserves and reflects the subobject classifier?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I'm stuck in the apparently easy exercise in the title; I tried to prove it twice but both arguments were flawed (one of the two: one can easily obtain a natural map $Sub_\mathcal E(A)\to Sub_\mathcal E(f_*A)$, but this is rarely an equivalence). A friend of mine proposed me a counterexample but I can't retrieve his proof... any clue?

Comment: Could you define "geometric" morphism?

Comment: a couple of adjoint functors $f^*\dashv f_*$, such that $f^*\colon \cal F\to E$ commutes with finite limits.

Comment: thank you, I just found it in Wikipedia too

Comment: you're welcome; does the question is so hard nobody has a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good candidate for a counterexamples is a "global section" functor
$\Gamma={\cal E}(1,-):{\cal E}\to{\cal S}et$ from ${\cal E}$ to Sets.
If ${\cal E}$ has all (small) coproducts (e.g. is a presheaf topos) then
$\Gamma$ is the direct part of a geometric morphism.

Now consider the topos ${\cal G}$ of directed Graphs (with loops and multiple
edges allowed). Then ${\cal G}(1,X)$ are just the loops of the graph $X$.
Since the subobject classifier $\Omega$ has 3 different loops, the set
$\Gamma(\Omega)$ has $3$ elements and cannot be equal to $2$.
Also $\Gamma(2)=2$ but $2\not\cong\Omega$ in ${\cal G}$.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about two points or provide me a reference?
1) The category of directed graphs is a topos and 2) its sub classifier has 3 different loops. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice your comment earlier. The category ${\cal G}$ is
just the presheaf category ${{\cal S}et^{\mathfrak{a}^op}}$ where
$\mathfrak{a} = \{D\rightrightarrows A\}$ is the full subcategory of $\cal G$
given by $D=\bullet$ and $A=\bullet\to\bullet$. As to the
loops of $\Omega$, note that the maps in ${\cal G}(1,\Omega)$ must correspond 
o the (three different) subobjects of $1$ (which are $\emptyset$, $D$ and $1$
itself).